# How to remove dates from start and end of the x-axis in Bokeh?

Tags: python, plot, bokeh

I am using Bokeh to plot amount against time in hours but the x-axis starts with the date `1/01` and ends with `1/02`. I want to replace the dates with time maybe like `00:00`.

Here is how the plot is looking at the moment:

[image]

And the code I am using is:

```
p = figure(plot_width=1000, plot_height=500, x_axis_type="datetime")
p.circle(df.Time, df.Amount)
p.xaxis.axis_label = 'Time'
p.yaxis.axis_label = 'Amount'
show(p)
```

Any suggestions will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`DatetimeTickFormatter`](https://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/reference/models/formatters.html#bokeh.models.formatters.DatetimeTickFormatter) has configurable properties that control how datetime values at different scales are formatted. So you can set e.g.

```py
p.xaxis[0].formatter.days = ['%H:%M']  # or ['%Hh'] if you prefer
```

Note that the `[0]` is necessary in this case, since "splattable" property setting on the list of axes only works one level deep.